# auto execute access on newly created stored procedure in sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server

I have given execute access to already existing procedures by running the below query:

```
grant execute on <schema_name>.<procedure_name> to <user_name>
```

But I have to run this query every time a new procedure is created. To solve this, i tried creating `db_executor_role` by running below query:

```
CREATE ROLE db_executor;
GRANT EXECUTE TO db_executor
```

and then assigning the user to this role by

*Security -> login -> user_name -> rightclick -> properties -> User Mapping -> select db -> check db_executor*.

But when I am trying to create a procedure through another user I am getting the below error:

```
Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Procedure Server_DDL_Audit, Line 23
The INSERT permission was denied on the object 'ChangeLog', database 'master', schema 'dbo'.
```

I am not able to resolve this. Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 0):

For the DDL trigger to insert into the master database table, you'll need to grant `INSERT` permissions on the table to either `public` or `guest`.

With DML triggers and other schema-scoped modules, you could use module signing but unfortunately that's not an option with DDL triggers.

Comment: but i haven't created any triggers. Moreover, i am not passing any insert query. i m just trying with a select query. Also, the user i am trying with has select, insert ,update,delete,create procedure and execute access on the database.

Comment: Also, if there is any other way out to grant auto execute access to new procedures, please let me know.

Comment: @anonymous, your `GRANT EXECUTE TO db_executor` will allow those role members to execute both existing and new stored procedures.