# Incorrect syntax near '.' while creating procedure

Tags: sql-server

I am getting the below error while trying to create a new procedure

> (1 row(s) affected) Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near '.'.

Please help me to resolve it. I have created a simple procedure as below.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test1
AS
BEGIN
    select 
    * 
    from dbo.proc_table
END;
```

Comment: Looking at your Sample Code. I does not seems like there are any issues in this code. Can you provide the actual one ?

Comment: try to run `CREATE PROCEDURE test1
AS
BEGIN
    select 
    * 
    from proc_table
END`

Comment: It seems that there is a ddl trigger in your db. When you create a proc successfully, you only get "Command(s) completed successfully.", NO rows affected. If you do CREATE PROC and receive rows affected, it means that smth else did smth

Comment: If you and your DBA intend to use DDL triggers (as evidenced by your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51984277/auto-execute-access-on-newly-created-stored-procedure-in-sql-server-2012) you collectively will need to master tsql and master tsql debugging. Now is the time to start discussing this sort of problem with dba - problem solving is far easier to do when you have access to the environment.